# How do I avoid repeating boilerplate code in angular controllers?

Tags: angularjs

Let's say I have 3 entitites: user, group, page. All three have a template in which I can edit them, as well as do other things that are unique to each.

I find that each control has some nearly identical code, leading to repetitive boilerplate and violating DRY. The following is pseudocode:

```
self.editMode = false; // to indicate mode we are in
self.edit = function(){self.editMode = true;}; // to enter edit mode
self.save = function(form) {
    self.item.save(function(err) {
       if (err) {
          // mark it on the form appropriately
       } else {
          self.editMode = false; // successfully done
          // also put a "Saved" message up
       }
    });
});
self.cancel = function(form) {
    self.item.$reset();
    // reset the form, clear entries, etc.
    self.editMode = false;
};
```

To do this in every controller is absurdly repetitive. Is there a proper angular way to do this? I was thinking perhaps of a service to decorate the controller, but that seems a bit of a strange use for a service.

Any better ideas?

UPDATE

I think this decoration is what Jussi is suggesting?

```
mod.factory('EditableCtrlrService',function() {
  return {
    makeEditable: function(ctrlr,item) {
        ctrlr.editMode = false; // to indicate mode we are in
        ctrlr.edit = function(){ctrlr.editMode = true;}; // to enter edit mode
        ctrlr.save = function(form) {
            item.save(function(err) {
               if (err) {
                  // mark it on the form appropriately
               } else {
                  ctrlr.editMode = false; // successfully done
                  // also put a "Saved" message up
               }
            });
        });
        ctrlr.cancel = function(form) {
          item.$reset();
          // reset the form, clear entries, etc.
          ctrlr.editMode = false;
        };
      }
    };
})
.controller('MyCtrl',function(EditableCtrlrService) {
  EditableCtrlrService.makeEditable(self);
  //  everything else unique to this controller
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A service is fine for this, this is fairly analogous to how you define resources in [`ngResource`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource). Just make sure the service works with objects that encompass their own functionality rather than sending the controller's scope to the service.

Comment: thanks for this. Can you elaborate further on "with objects that encompass their own functionality"? Do you mean that the service should provide a static function to decorate the controller, and this the controller should call it?

Comment: The service should ideally not rely on a controller. It could, for example, be used to create objects that have save/edit/cancel-methods. These could then return promises where you put your controller-specific code. It really depends on the types of things you need to do in your controller.

Comment: If you need to handle data based on a form or other UI-based feature, it might be easier to create a directive that takes in the type of resource and varies its logic and/or template based on that parameter.

Comment: I think I see where you are going. I had understood your suggestion as injecting the service, and then using the service to decorate the controller. See my edit above.

Comment: Ok, after re-reading the question, the decorating aspect of it may not be the best approach. You might be attempting to do too much in your controller, splitting functionality into services and directives where appropriate is probably the cleanest way to do it.

Comment: Jussi, I just updated the original question to illustrate how I understood the decoration. Is that not what you were suggesting? It would seem that these basic edit/save/cancel are perfectly suited to a controller - they control the state of the UI and pass requests from it back to an underlying service. How would you do this differently?

Comment: I meant returning an object from the service and using those methods/propertied directly, the object would manage its own data and define an interface usable by the controller and anything else that might want to use it.